# Create new DataFrame with new rows depending in number of a column - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with the following data:

```
  num_cta   | n_lines
110000000000|   2
110100000000|   3
110200000000|   1
```

With that information, I need to create a new DF with different number of rows depending the value that comes over the **n_lines** column.

For example, for the first row of my DF (**110000000000**), the value of the *n_lines* column is **2**. The result would have to be something like the following:

```
  num_cta   
110000000000
110000000000
```

For all the Dataframe example that I show, the result to get would have to be something like this:

```
  num_cta  
110000000000
110000000000
110100000000
110100000000
110100000000
110200000000
```

Is there a way to do that? And multiply a row **n** times, depending on the value of a column value?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to expand `n_lines` into an array with an UDF and `explode` it:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("110000000000", 2),
  ("110100000000", 3),
  ("110200000000", 1)
)toDF("num_cta", "n_lines")

def fillArr = udf(
  (n: Int) => Array.fill(n)(1)
)

val df2 = df.withColumn("arr", fillArr($"n_lines")).
  withColumn("a", explode($"arr")).
  select($"num_cta")

df2.show
+------------+
|     num_cta|
+------------+
|110000000000|
|110000000000|
|110100000000|
|110100000000|
|110100000000|
|110200000000|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no off the shelve way to doing this. However you can try iterate over the dataframe and return a list of num_cta where the number of elements are equal to the corresponding n_lines.

Something like

```
 import spark.implicits._

 case class (num_cta:String) // output dataframe schema
 case class (num_cta:String, n_lines:Integer) // input dataframe 'df' schema

val result =  df.flatmap(x => {
     List.fill(x.n_lines)(x.num_cta) 
 }).toDF
```